# startActivityForResult is deprecated

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-12

I have this blocks of codes from the a class, which is extended by ActivityX. I have two startActivityForResult need to be fixed and I dont know how to implement the new API.

**This is the 1st startActivityForResult.**

```
    private void launchIntentToAddPackToSpecificPackage(String identifier, String stickerPackName, String whatsappPackageName) {
        Intent intent = createIntentToAddStickerPack(identifier, stickerPackName);
        intent.setPackage(whatsappPackageName);
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_PACK);

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.add_pack_fail_prompt_update_whatsapp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

**This is the 2nd startActivityForResult.**

```
    //Handle cases either of WhatsApp are set as default app to handle this intent. We still want users to see both options.
    private void launchIntentToAddPackToChooser(String identifier, String stickerPackName) {
        Intent intent = createIntentToAddStickerPack(identifier, stickerPackName);
        try {
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.add_to_whatsapp)), ADD_PACK);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.add_pack_fail_prompt_update_whatsapp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

**This is the OnActivityResult.**

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == ADD_PACK) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                if (data != null) {
                    final String validationError = data.getStringExtra("validation_error");
                    if (validationError != null) {
                        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                            //validation error should be shown to developer only, not users.
                            MessageDialogFragment.newInstance(R.string.title_validation_error, validationError).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "validation error");
                        }
                        Log.e(TAG, "Validation failed:" + validationError);
                    }
                } else {
                    new StickerPackNotAddedMessageFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "sticker_pack_not_added");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [This](https://medium.com/realm/startactivityforresult-is-deprecated-82888d149f5d) might help you

Answer (score 0):

You can update it like this
**1st startActivityForResult.**

```
private void launchIntentToAddPackToSpecificPackage(String identifier, String stickerPackName, String whatsappPackageName) {
    Intent intent = createIntentToAddStickerPack(identifier, stickerPackName);
    intent.setPackage(whatsappPackageName);
    launchIntentSpecific.launch(intent);
}

private ActivityResultLauncher < Intent > launchIntentSpecific = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
    new ActivityResultCallback < ActivityResult > () {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Intent data = result.getData();
                if (data != null) {
                    final String validationError = data.getStringExtra("validation_error");
                    if (validationError != null) {
                        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                            //validation error should be shown to developer only, not users.

                            MessageDialogFragment.newInstance(R.string.title_validation_error,
                                validationError).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "validation error");
                        }
                        Log.e(TAG, "Validation failed:" + validationError);
                    }
                } else {
                    new StickerPackNotAddedMessageFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                        "sticker_pack_not_added");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Request codes are removed in the new implementations